# How do you set up a non-expiring token for an Azure DevOps Agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My Azure DevOps agent at the moment uses a personal access token assigned to a user which expires after a year.  I was wondering can it be set up to use a service account that has a non-expiring password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to regenerate a token. You use it only for configuration: [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#server-url-and-authentication)

> When using PAT as the authentication method, the PAT token is only
> used during the initial configuration of the agent. Later, if the PAT
> expires or needs to be renewed, no further changes are required by the
> agent.